# Having issues with font size

Tags: fontsize, paper-size

I am creating a 6x9 version of my normally letter sized document. The font size does not seem to be working correctly, however. The 6x9 document is set up for 12pt using the book class, while the letter size version is set up for 11pt also using the book class. As you can see, this is not correct, however. Both PDFs are open at 100% width, and the difference in the font size is obvious. The weird thing is that the 6x9 is a copy of the letter sized version, just made 1 column and without images. Any clues?

[image]

PS: the letter size has this declaration:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,letterpaper,titlepage,twocolumn,openany]{book}
```

while the 6x9 was modified to this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,titlepage,openany]{book}
```

and I am using the geometry page to set the doc size like this:

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in, paperheight=8.5in]{geometry}
```

EDIT: I also just noticed that my paragraph indentation is not working. I am going to start taking pieces out one at a time to see what happens.

Comment: Are you making an RPG? Cool. Anyway, there's nothing in the code you posted to explain the behavior. Removing things bit by bit is a good idea. We need a [MWE](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=tex+stackexchange+minimal+working+example). At least post all packages and settings related to fonts. (Those clearly are not the default.)

Comment: Actually, I am! And also, I found this issue. When I was trying to set up a MWE by pasting the main stuff into a completely fresh doc it fixed it. That let me trace it back and found a naked \scriptsize that was causing it. Still trying to figure out why the paragraph indents aren't working, but I'm getting closer on that regard.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP found the answer himself (see his answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. As expected it was my own fault. I had a naked \scriptsize, that was causing the issues. I fixed that and the only problem that remains is unrelated, so outside the scope of this question. Thanks.